# Azure Log Analytics from multiple tenants

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-log-analytics, azure-service-principal

I'm building a C# MVC webapp.
The plan is:

1. First time user creates a custom account
2. When logged in, **add a tenant with Microsoft OAuth2**, agree to permissions
3. The webapp aggregates pre-configured Log Analytics items for each user's onboarded tenants.

How do I handle multitenant onboarding, where one user supplies multiple tenant accounts?

How do I authenticate and authorise once and call Azure APIs forever?

Comment: You can just create an multi-tenant app and config the required permissions  that you will need to call Azure APIs. Details, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant
let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but they do not answer my questions. @StanleyGong a multi-tenant app works if I want to log in as different users from different tenants, but if I want to be logged in as two different users from different tenants and access their Log Analytics both at once, I would need to do programming gymnastics to come close with it.

Comment: The same thing was discussed here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/multi-tenant-centralize-log-analytics/m-p/901413, but there's no mention of how it could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[Multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) mentioned by @StanleyGong should make sense.

In this case, you can [add your account as guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal) to the multiple tenants, [assign RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) to give the user access to the Azure Log Analytics.

Configure the authority as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}` for multiple tenants in a configuration file. When you sign in with this account, choose different tenant based on different `{tenant-id}`.

You cannot sign in once to access to all the Azure Log Analytics data from all tenants. And you also can't authenticate and authorize once and call Azure APIs forever. [Access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) has lifetime. After it expires, you should re-authenticate.

Comment: I want the inverse of what you proposed. You said to add accounts as guest to a tenant, I want multiple accounts, i.e. accounts that belong to different tenants to be grouped into a single login, that can access Log Analytics from all those different tenants. I know some Citrix software was doing it, but with virtual machines.

Comment: @LukasAntanavičius What do you mean by "multiple accounts, i.e. accounts that belong to different tenants to be grouped into a single login"? Can you share a sample or any screenshots?

Comment: For example: we have the main tenant, which queries Log Analytics. I want to send data from many other tenants to the main tenant. The main tenant then can aggregate Log Analytics data from many tenants.